# Unknown network file on my IMac

Tags: network

I have an unknown network file on my iMac, it appears in the sidebar of Finder, under 'Shared'.  It is called hp3464a93ca02a.  What is this and can I delete it if it is unnecessary?  It has been present for over a year, maybe two and I can attribute no ill effects to it; seems benign, perhaps even helpful.  Just wondering...

Comment: Are you on a network which has an HP device on it, such as another computer, networked printer, etc? That name would seem very much like a vendor (HP) + its MAC (physical) address (34-64-A9-3C-A0-2A) which is sharing services across the network.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a very similar name in my Finder sidebar as well.

It's an HP product (mine's a printer) that is on your local network that has been setup to be accessible over the network. It disappears when the printer is not powered on.

As "smoooosher" said, its name is identical to the MAC address of the device.